# Uncheck "allow only this type of editing in the document" option

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop, office-automation

How to not display gray color and brackets after disabling word document protection **with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` library in C#**.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpVNd.jpg)

How to uncheck "Allow only this type of editing in the document".

Comment: What code have you tried so far? How is the Word interop related to option on the screenshot? Do you need to set it up programmatically?

Comment: I just unprotect document but nothing so far....
'if (wordDoc.ProtectionType != WdProtectionType.wdNoProtection)
   wordDoc.Unprotect("123");'

Answer (score 0):

The Word object model provides the [Protect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.protect) method of the `Document` class which provides a bunch of various parameters. So, you may play with parameters to uncheck the option from a screenshot.

Comment: Yes, I worked with this method and there is no result.
The point is that I want to unprotect a Word document without any editing restrictions while this method does the opposite.